# How to make asynctask work properly

Tags: android

I have a button on my app, if the user click it, it will refresh the current page by calling onResume(), and there are lots of database operations in onResume(). Instead of keeping the button stay pressed for a while, I would like to use asynctask to make a progressdialog while loading the data. But the problem is that the button will still be in pressed state and the progressdialog only show at the end of the operation for a very short duration.

```
RefreshButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                onResume();
            }
        });

protected void onResume()
    {
        doneloading = false;
        monResumeloading = new onResumeloading();
        monResumeloading.execute();
        ....loading...

            doneloading = true;
    }

private class onResumeloading extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String>
    {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(StatisticsActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.show();

            Log.i(TAG, "              doneloading=false");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
        {

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Integer... params)
        {
            while(!doneloading)
            {
                publishProgress(0);   //dummy
                            log.i(TAG, "loading");
            }
            return null;
        }


    }
```

I observed that the "loading" log is showing right after the asynctask execution and stop right after the boolean doneloading becomes false. But the progressdialog is not working properly. Please help me :(

Answer (score 2):

First thing, I don't think you should be calling your AsyncTask in the onResume() function.  You can simply call it from your ClickListener.

Right now, you are doing your '....loading...' code before you even execute your AsyncTask.  That's why the button stays pressed while it's executing '....loading...' and then when it's done, it executes your AsyncTask which really isn't doing anything - that's why it just shows up for a short duration.

Move your '....loading...' code into your doInBackground() of your AsyncTask and it should work ok.

Summary:

1. Click: Execute AsyncTask
2. AsyncTask: opens ProgressDialog
3. AsyncTask: Executes your '...loading...' code
4. AsyncTask: Wait for '...loading...' code to complete while still displaying dialog.
5. AsyncTask: Dismiss ProgressDialog

Comment: thanks for your time, what happen if I dont want to move my code out of my onResume() method?

Comment: I think it should still work but it's just an odd place to put it.  Because lets say you move on to the next Activity and then hit Back.  It's going to call the onResume() function and thus execute your '...loading...' and AsyncTask functions again.

Comment: I think I executed the asynctask before the .....loading.... code
And because I need to update the UI(UI contains some graph and info) everything the user comes back from another activity, that why I put all those codes inside onResume, it will be a headache if I need to move those codes into the private asynctask class...

Comment: I executed the asynctask in the very beginning of onResume() and after that I do the ...loading...

Comment: Ah, I misread that.  However, the same idea still applies.  If you want the Progress Dialog to display during the time it takes for '...loading..' to complete, you need to put it in the AsyncTask.  You have to think of your Activity and the AsyncTasks as two different threads (b/c they are).

Comment: the problem is that I need to update the UI and views. And that couldn't be place in asynctask, the system will throw a fatal exception saying only the thread that create the view can modify it

Comment: I place the execute on the button listener, same thing happen